# Stop User From Interacting with UiPath Robots

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I’ve deployed a UiPath robot with Picture in Picture but the RPA process can still be broken by the user typing into a text field or clicking a button in the PiP frame.

How do you stop the user from interfering with the UiPath robot? I thought that’s what UiPath Picture in Picture was for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UiPath Picture-in-Picture feature is a good way to isolate the process, but it won't completely block user input. For that, you need the aptly named [Block User Input](https://www.rpacertified.com//2021/02/04/block-user-input-tutorial-uipath.html) Activity in UiPath Studio.

[image]

### Block User Input Activity

The UiPath Block User Input Activity will stop the user's keyboard and mouse from being able to interact with the RPA process running in [UiPath's Picture-in-Picture](https://www.rpacertified.com/2021/02/04/picture-in-picture-pip-uipath.html) window.

There is an escape mechanism though. If the user does need to break into the [PiP window](https://youtu.be/KOjVaJ7aPdA), an escape key sequence can be set on the Block User Input activity. When this hotkey or escape sequence is entered, the block user input functionality is disabled and it's possible to once again send keyboard input or mouse clicks to the RPA robot.